# How to hide fields on a SOAP web service

Tags: api, rest, soap

How can I make an API that will make sure the client side does not show its users fields that are irrelevant to my application?

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but it doesn't seem very clear what it is you're trying to do/prevent.

Comment: I have a website that revolves around transactions between two users. Each user needs to agree to the same terms. If I want an API so other websites can implement this into their own website, then I want to make sure that the other websites cannot mess with the process by including more fields in between or things that are irrelevant to my application. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide it in the WSDL. The whole point of discovery is to determine this.

However you can lock down the APIs you support by providing a client side library that only exposes the functions you want.

You'll need to create one for each platform you support.

Comment: I have a website that revolves around transactions between two users. Each user needs to agree to the same terms. If I want an API so other websites can implement this into their own website, then I want to make sure that the other websites cannot mess with the process by including more fields in between or things that are irrelevant to my application. Is this possible?